# Sliding window std calculation

Tags: python, numpy

I got raster with float values (from Sentinel-1) data cut to lake shape. It has nodata value of 255. Importing it to numpy masked array.

Now would like to create an array with STD value of neighbouring pixels in given range (in pixels) of every pixel. For example +/- 5 pixels around (in x,y dimensions). Of course in that STD calculation to not to take the center pixel (the one that we are calculating surroundings information) value into an account.

What I have implemented for now is a "brute force" method (and it works as expected, lake is the masked array of lake pixel values):

```
lake_std = np.full(lake.shape, 255, dtype=float)
pixels_around = 5
w, h = lake.shape
for x in range(0, w):
    for y in range(0, h):
        left = x - pixels_around
        right = x + pixels_around + 1
        top = y - pixels_around
        bottom = y + pixels_around + 1
        cx = pixels_around
        cy = pixels_around
        if left < 0:
            cx = cx + left
            left = 0
        if right > w + 1: # this is not really needed
            right = w + 1
        if top < 0:
            cy = cy + top
            top = 0
        if bottom > h + 1: # this is not really needed
            bottom = h + 1    
        tmp = np.copy(lake[left: right, top: bottom])
        tmp[cx][cy] = 255
        if np.any((tmp != 255)):
            lake_std[x][y] = np.std(tmp, where=(tmp != 255))
```

Is there any better / faster / more vectorized method to do the same? It seems to be pretty slow.
Please note that I will have to do other statistics as well (like MEAN or whatever)

Before I was trying to implement it using `sliding_window_view` built-in function, but it didn't seem to change much in the calculation speed and there was a problem with pixels near the border of an image.

Comment: Possibly more help on stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216770 https://stackoverflow.com/a/46237736

Comment: to be honest it's more or less the same solution, just with a generator (but interiors are pretty the same); mine additionaly got support for partial windows =>2x2